# Create post loop that displays pages by cat ID

Tags: plugins, loop

I've figured a way to assign categories to a PAGE, in which I want to create a loop for a page template, so if the user has viewed that page, it displays all the PAGES within that category.

Here's my loop:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=540'); ?>
```

```
                            <div class="blog_module">


                                            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                                the_post_thumbnail(array(150,150));
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<img class="alignleft" src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/empty_150_150_thumb.gif" width="150" height="150" />';
                                            }
                                            ?>


                                            <div class="entry">
                                                <h3 class="blog_header"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                <a class="button_link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More</span></a>

                                            </div>  


                                    </div>
```

I added a test PAGE and test POST, but as the image below shows, it only pulls through the POST:
[image]

Please could you share a post loop that will pull in PAGES if the PAGES have been assigned to that category.

Thanks.

**Update**

Code for creating the taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_page_taxonomies' );
function create_page_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('page_category', 'page', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Page Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'page-category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Page Categories' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Page Categories' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Page Category' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Page Category:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Page Category' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Page Category' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Page Category' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Page Category Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Page Categories' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'page-category',
            'with_front' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: How you assigned categories to the pages? By default categories are only for posts and not for pages.

Comment: Check updated..